# Mnemonical phrases/verses/songs for Japanese grammar

Tags: discussion, resources

In Russian, we have mnemonical phrases for memorizing things like grammatical cases, conjugations of verbs, detecting adverbs, etc. They are somewhat similar to [Roy G. Biv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROYGBIV) mnemonic, but most often are rhymed in a manner of songs for little children. You can find examples here: http://www.gramota.ru/class/memos/ - I don't know if there are equivalents of these in English, sorry.

Are there any similar phrases/verses/songs in Japanese? I'm specifically interested in ones related to grammar, e.g. memorizing counter suffixes (助数詞).

Comment: But I'm afraid "五段動詞 which end with -る" is the most productive verb type... http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1318104978

Comment: There's an obscure pop song that happens to adopt some conjugations in the lyrics though it's not for educational purpose. https://youtu.be/QCkRBxJxoQA?t=34

Comment: @broccoliforest I mean verbs like 切る, 知る, 帰る, 入る, 走る, etc. Maybe it's not a good example, but it's the simplest analogy I could think of.

Comment: @scriptin According to [this article](http://homepage3.nifty.com/jgrammar/ja/colum001.htm#mottomo), Japanese has at least 75 simple 五段 verbs (200 or more if you count complex ones) you can't tell from 一段. So my advice is you memorize the 否定形 together: 要る-要らない vs 居る-居ない etc.

Comment: @broccoliforest this is a great suggestion, seems much more convenient than just trying to memorize the verb type. So, this example is invalid, I'll remove it from my question.

Comment: A little song for remembering grammar but I feel like you won't need that kind of grammar anytime soon. [助動詞の歌](https://youtu.be/9XHCS5lgquc)

Comment: @scriptin There's a song for て-form formula you can find in youtube. But for other grammars i haven't seen it yet. For vocabulary (verbs, adj, noun) mnemonics though, easy-japan.tumblr.com seems to develop mnemonics card for kanji and spelling. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Here is one I know for U VERB て form. It's sung to the Battle Hymn of the Republic. Here's a link for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s0ZRSpZMWI

あう、あって
まつ、まって
とる、とって

読む、読んで
遊ぶ、遊んで
死ぬ、死んで

かく、かいて
消す、消して
急ぐ、急いで

みんな　U VERB て　フォーム！

Answer (score 0):

There is the [[伊呂波]{い・ろ・は}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha) if you can memorize it, but it's not for grammar.  It's mostly used to remember the kana and for ["ordering" things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha#Current_Uses).

Not sure if that really helps you though.

Comment: It's interesting to know, but unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for.